# Querying an array in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am sure this has been asked before but I am struggling to find a correct answer. I'm using Swift 3. Here's the problem:

I have a list of postID's in an array. I now want to query Firebase and if the postID exists, then retrieve the data and display it in my tableview.

What's the recommended way to do this ? Any code examples would be of great help. Ideally I would want to get all the posts and then update the table view in one shot. Thanks.

To be clear I am looking for the Firebase Query here that will help me achieve this.

Firebase structure

[image: Firebase Post Structure]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

first create database reference till post

```
let mainRef = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")
```

Now suppose you have post id in `myPostID` variable

```
 mainRef.child(myPostID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            if let  value = snapshot.value {
               // Value FOUND UPDATE YOUR TABLE HERE
            } else {
              // No ID found for this post
            }
  }
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: myPostId here is actually one id from the array. So would i put this in a For loop so i can iterate through all the ids ?

Comment: @NetCod You don't have postID to show ? you have array of ids and you want a single id that exits in firebase databse ?

Comment: @NetCod You can't search  directly array to the firebase.